# school math, equations and minimal steps problem

Tags: integer-programming

I have the following problem:
$ X(20A + 88C) + Y(32B + 72C) + Z(40A + 40B) \ge 616A + 890B + 982C$

the second condition is that the sum of $ X + Y + Z $ should be as low as possible.

If there is more than 1 solution possible, i need only 1.

EDIT: X Y and Z are whole numbers!

---

what i tried so faar
making three equations

$ 20X + 40Z = 616 $

$ 32Y + 40Z = 890 $

$ 88X + 72Y = 982 $

---

p.s. what sort of math is this ? i tagged it with linear-algebra.

Comment: "*What sort of math is this?*"  [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Comment: thanks, updated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ constants or unknowns?

Comment: they are constants! (had to search the term "unknowns" first)

Comment: After your edit about whole numbers, this is *integer linear programming*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your three equality constraints are infeasible; that is, they cannot simultaneously be satisfied.  If you relax $=$ to $\ge$, the minimum $X+Y+Z$ turns out to be $28$, attained by $(X,Y,Z)=(3,10,15)$.

<s>But depending on the values of $A$, $B$, and $C$, you might be able to satisfy your original inequality constraint with a smaller $X+Y+Z$.</s>

Here's a proof of optimality, obtained via linear programming duality.  Multiply the three inequality constraints by $17/1330$, $13/1064$, and $9/1064$, respectively, and add them up:
$$\frac{17}{1330}(20X+40Z)+\frac{13}{1064}(32Y+40Z)+\frac{9}{1064}(88X+72Y)\\
\ge
\frac{17}{1330}\cdot 616+\frac{13}{1064}\cdot 890+\frac{9}{1064}\cdot 982,$$
which simplifies to $X+Y+Z \ge 27+36/665$.  Because the objective must be integer-valued, $28$ is a lower bound.  The $(3,10,15)$ solution attains this bound and is hence optimal.

Comment: First of all thanks for bothering with that question!
I see your concern about A B and C.
How can i describe that...A B and C are not numbers, lets say A stands for Apples, B for Bananas and C for Carrots. That was bad on my behalf, i thought thats called constants.

I will give you the Checkmark if noone finds a lower solution.
(i can´t verify it, otherwise i wouldn´t have asked in first place)

Anyway, is it too much to ask for the solution steps ? So that i could understand and verify that this is the correct answer.

Comment: I added a short proof of optimality.

Comment: Lets say i understand how you get to the 28.
I don´t quite get how you came across those big numbers ? (1330 and 1064)
And how do you know that the distribution has to be 3,10,15? (but that was not part of the original question).
So there goes your checkmark!

Comment: To find the optimal integer solution $(3,10,15)$, I used an integer linear programming solver.  To find the magic dual multipliers with the big denominators, I used a linear programming solver.